# Re-scaling div content without resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am looking for a solution to re-scaling the contents of a div with a fixed width and height.
Right now i have a div like so :

```
<div id="editor_preview" style="width:360px !important;
                                color:gray;
                                margin-top:40px;
                                position:absolute;
                                overflow:auto;
                                height:190px !important">
</div>
```

I am loading dynamic HTML content into this div, by the use of CKEditor ( http://ckeditor.com/ )

Since the input text may contain different font sizes, I am looking for a way to downscale the contents on overflow.

The way I'm trying right now is using javascript and the zoom function like so :

```
document.getElementById(ev.editor.name + '_preview').innerHTML = ev.editor.getData();
var container = document.getElementById(ev.editor.name + '_preview');
var i = 99.9;

if (container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight) {
    while (container.scrollHeight > container.clientHeight) {

        container.style.zoom = i + "%";
        i -= 0.1;
    }
}
```

However ; this also decreases the size of the div to match the content. So in short what i want is :

- Keep the div size
- Downscale the content
- No overflow

Comment: Have you tried using the min-height and max-height tags in addition to the height and width tags?

Comment: Sorry for not putting that in my post, but yes, I have tried that. Unfortunately the 'zoom' function seems to override these arguments. Probably have to use a different form of zoom, I just have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Maybe try, when the zoom first changes, putting the contents of the div into a sub-div, and zoom that sub-div?

Comment: Won't I get the same effect? The idea is to scale down the content, making place for more content. I think with what you are suggesting I will keep the original div's size, just a new, smaller div inside of that. Or am I misinterpreting your idea?

Comment: You're interpreting it right, I must have interpreted your question incorrectly.  Apologies.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you are trying to make the font-size small if the content overflows the container right?

Comment: Correct, that's the basic idea. Keeping in mind that the rest of the text markup must stay the same. So if 1 word would be fontsize 20px, and another 10px, it should downscale to respectively 10px and 5px (at least, values that maintain the aspect-ratio). Ofcourse, I'd still like to fill the div with the content, so downscaling too much wouldn't be good.

Comment: if all the units of font-sizes are same: `var fontSize = parseInt(elem.style.fontSize, 10); elem.style.fontSize = (fontSize - percentage) + "px";` .. just an idea to you.

Comment: The suggestion makes sense, I've just tried it out. It works when all my content is the same font-size, however when I have different spans with different fontSizes the script causes my browser to crash. (Again, the content is dynamic so I don't know what the html-content of the div may look like)

Comment: You should run the above code for each span element in a for loop in the container where variable `percentage` is constant through each loop. Anyway, I don't think this is as an ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input Mr_Green, with the code you posted I've managed to achieve my goal, though I've disabled many options in the editor so  the font-size is constant. Sacrificing features to make this scale across devices appropriately seems fair enough for now. Nonetheless, I'm quite interested in what the possibilities are for maybe a future update!

Comment: Since your content is dynamic, it might not be a feasible option, but there is also the jQuery plugin FitText.js that attempts to do this. http://fittextjs.com/ Although this plugin is more for titles and shorter bits of text.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark here. Seems like you're doing things above my skill level, but what about using rem? Then controlling it with font-size: 50%;?

**CSS**

```
body{
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#editor_preview{
    font-size: 50%; // control text size here
}
```